# Django restrict user to edit data which doesnt belongs to them

Tags: django

I have a url,

```
path('faculty/edit/<str:pk>/', faculty.edit_form, name="faculty-edit"),
path('faculty/delete/<str:pk>', faculty.delete, name="faculty-delete"),

localhost:8000/user/faculty/edit/1
```

In the above, 1 is the data's id which belongs to user=x ! Likewise i have 1000's of data

Now when i log in as user=y and go the same link, it opens the edit page ! But data 1 is belongs to user=x - how to handle this ? How to restrict this ?

Does django do this automatically or we need to do this manually ?

My edit view:

```
def edit_form(request, pk):
    faculty = Faculty.objects.get(id=pk)
    
    form = AddFacultyForm(instance=faculty)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddFacultyForm(request.POST, instance=faculty)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('faculty')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'faculty/edit_form.html', context)
```

Now adding models,

```
#Faculty
from django.db import models
from .profile import University

class Faculty(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(University, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    faculty_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

#Univ Profile
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from unireo.users.models import User

class University(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Can you please share the urls and view.

Comment: Have made update, do check @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @sixvov947: how is the `Faculty` linked to the logged in user?

Comment: Faculty is liked to Profile, and Profile is liked to User

Comment: and this is all with a `OneToOneField`? Perhaps it is worth to share the `Faculty`, `Profile` and `User` model (`User` if you made a custom user model).

Comment: can you show us the `Faculty` model?

Comment: I have added Faculty & Profile @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0):

In the view we can filter the `Faculty` object such that the `Faculty` has a `Profile` that is linked to the logged in user with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required
def edit_form(request, pk):
    faculty = get_object_or_404(Faculty, id=pk, owner__user=request.user)
    # …
```

this will return a HTTP 404 answer if the request is made by a user to which the `Faculty` object is *not* related.

I would also advise if the primary keys are numerical to work with the [**`<int:…>`** path converter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) to only "fire" the view if the primary key is a sequence of digits, not any string:

```
path('faculty/edit/<int:pk>/', faculty.edit_form, name='faculty-edit'),
path('faculty/delete/<int:pk>/', faculty.delete, name='faculty-delete'),
```

You can instead return a redirect with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect

@login_required
def edit_form(request, pk):
    try:
        faculty = get_object_or_404(Faculty, id=pk, owner__user=request.user)
    except Http404:
        return redirect('%%%name-of-some-view%%%')
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Whats the standard way of checking if the data belongs to the user ? is that get_object_or_404 or is there something better ?

Comment: @sixovov947: it is the `owner__user=request.user` filter in the `get_object_or_404(...)`. The `get_object_or_404(...)` will simply try to fetch an object that matches, and if not raise a `Http404` such that for another user, editing a faculty of another university will return a HTTP 404 response.

Comment: I understand that, thank you ! Just curious to know if there is any other standard to deal this ? so that i can modify the code according to that ?

Comment: Also how to redirect to someother page instead of 404 ? Is that possible ?

Comment: @sixovov947: you can wrap the `get_object_or_404` in a `try:`-`except Http404:` (you import `Http404` with `from django.http import Http404`, and then in the catch a `return redirect` to some view.

Comment: Got it, thanks ! As the faculty is tied to Univ and Univ is tied to user ! How owner__user works ? is that should be owner_university_user ?

Comment: @sixovov947: it will make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the `University` (since the `ForeignKey` named `owner` points to that), it will add a `WHERE` clause on the `university.user_id = pk-of-the-user`.

Comment: @sixovov947: see for example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships